# Unity CSharp - Timer & Broadcast Message

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, timer, message

I personally could not find the answer on stackoverflow already, but my question is kind of basic, I just don't understand what I need to do in this scenario: If I have the following code, how would I use BroadcastMessage so that when my timer (myCT) is equal to 500 it displays a message in unity, Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class myTimer : MonoBehaviour 
{
  public float myCT = 600;
  public Text timerText;


  void Start () {
    timerText=GetComponent<Text>();
  }

  // countdown
  void Update () {
    myCT -= Time.deltaTime;
    timerText.text = myCT.ToString("f0");
    print (myCT);

    if(myCT = 598){
      //I want something to happen here using broadcast message()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't do anything like this.  simply use Invoke or perhaps InvokeRepeating for simple timers in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a countdown timer that is counting from 600 down  to 500.First of all, you compare stuff with `==` (`if(myCT = 598){}`) **not** with `=`. Because `myCT` is a `float`, it is never guaranteed to be **598** or **500** when decreasing. So you must use `<=` instead of `==`.

```
if(myCT = 598){

}
```

should be

```
if(myCT <= 500){
    Debug.Log("Timer reached!");
    BroadcastMessage("doSomthingFunction", 500.0F);
}
```

Comment: glance at the Doco first to learn a lot. notice the argument you can have ... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.BroadcastMessage.html

Comment: @JoeBlow This guy just deleted his comment. I dislike that because it makes other comments hard to understand.

Comment: That was quick, thanks so much. The only thing I'm wondering now is how to take the message from the log and display it on a GUI.

Comment: @programmer I apologize, my comment was that I kept getting a message saying, "doSomething" has no receiver! But I solved that later on. [The only thing I'm wondering now is how to take the message from the log and display it on a GUI. how to take "Timer reached!" and put it to a text GUI.] Sorry again for all of these questions, I have a project due really soon. I heard maybe Application.logmessagereceived could work. I just don't know what that does.

Comment: @SequoiaLawson You put the `timerText.text = "Timer reached!";` into the if statement in my answer...

Comment: @SequoiaLawson it's admirable to be tidy, but it's often best to *not* delete comments.  (I actually very often delete comments -- BUT -- a handy rule of thumb is, wait for a day or so until doing so.)